# Angular JS : show text box relatively based on click on radio button and change background color of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Oud.png)

I am new to angularjs. as shown in the image , by default linkedin radio button is selected.

but when i select on facebook radio button then two textboxes appears for 1 sec and hide the linked in textbox.

when i click on linkedin button then linked in textbox should appear and other textbox should get disappear and when i click on facebook radio button then facebook textbox should appear.

here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/28991/)

Thank You.

```css
  .social_icon_radio_toggle {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

label {
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

span {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}

input {
    position: absolute;
}

//wheather radio button is checked or not
input:checked + span {
    background-color: $linked_in_bg_color;
    color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 35px;
    line-height: 33px;
}

input:not(:checked + span) {
    background-color: #edf1f2;
    color: #58666e;
}

.linkedin {
    background-color: #edf1f2;
    color: #58666e;
    border: thin #a8a8a8 solid;
    color: #a8a8a8;
    line-height: 33px;
}

.facebook {
    background-color: #edf1f2;
    color: #58666e;
    border: thin #ced9db solid;
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 set_padding_0 social_icons_section">
    <div class="social_icon_radio_toggle">
        <label class="linkedin">
            <input type="radio" name="registration_options" checked="checked" ng-click="option='linkedin'" ng-init="option='linkedin'">
            <span><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> </span></label>
        <label class="facebook">
            <input type="radio" name="registration_options" ng-click="option='facebook'">
            <span><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </span></label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input class="form-control margin_top_4" placeholder="www.linkedin.com/example" type="text" ng-show="option == 'linkedin'" ng-hide="option == 'facebook'">
    </div>
    <input class="form-control margin_top_4" placeholder="www.facebook.com/example" type="text" ng-show="option == 'facebook'" ng-hide="option == 'linkedin'">
</div>
```

Comment: That is not a question, that is a request to write code...

Comment: i have already written a code but the textbox is getting switched. when i click on facebook radio button.

Comment: I can not see any angular code in your question or your fiddle.

Comment: Please add `angular.js` file to the fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
  .social_icon_radio_toggle{
    float: left; margin-right: 20px;
    }

    label {
      float:left;width:35px; height:35px;overflow:hidden;cursor: pointer !important; margin-right: 5px;}
      span {text-align:center;font-size: 15px;margin:auto;display: block;}
 

    input {position:absolute;}

    //wheather radio button is checked or not
    input:checked + span {background-color:$linked_in_bg_color;color:#fff; min-height: 100%; width: 35px; line-height: 33px;}
    input:not(:checked + span) {background-color:#edf1f2;color:#58666e;}
    .linkedin {background-color:#edf1f2;color: #58666e; border: thin #a8a8a8 solid;  color: #a8a8a8;line-height: 33px;}
    .facebook {background-color:#edf1f2;color: #58666e;border: thin #ced9db solid; line-height: 35px;}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 set_padding_0 social_icons_section">
                            <div class="social_icon_radio_toggle">
                                <label class="linkedin">
                                    <input type="radio" name="registration_options" checked="checked" ng-click="option='linkedin'" ng-init="option='linkedin'">
                                    <span><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> </span></label>
                                <label class="facebook" >
                                    <input type="radio" name="registration_options" ng-click="option='facebook'">
                                    <span><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </span></label>
                            </div>

                            <div type="text" ng-show="option === 'linkedin'" >
                                <input class="form-control " placeholder="www.linkedin.com/example" >
                            </div>
                            <div ng-show="option === 'facebook'">
                                <input class="form-control " placeholder="www.facebook.com/example" type="text" >
                            </div>


                        </div>
```

Here is updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/28993/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: you can see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034333/angularjs-change-font-awsome-icon-color-and-background-on-click/41375930?noredirect=1#comment69955773_41375930 . this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the directive ng-model to track the value of your 'option' property. Then set per every radio button the corresponding ng-value.

And take into account, that ng-show and ng-hide works in similar ways. It is not necessary to use both at the same time.
ng-hide = hide the element if the expression = true
ng-show = show the element if the expression = true

```
<label class="linkedin" >
<input type="radio" name="registration_options"  ng-model="option" ng-value="'linkedin'">
<span><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i> </span></label>
<label class="facebook" >
<input type="radio" name="registration_options" ng-value="'facebook'" ng-model="option">
 <span><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> </span></label>

<input class="form-control margin_top_4" placeholder="www.linkedin.com/example" type="text" ng-show="option == 'linkedin'">
<input class="form-control margin_top_4" placeholder="www.facebook.com/example" type="text" ng-show="option == 'facebook'">
```

Working Sample:
https://plnkr.co/edit/ezDAwU41vYKrw7DwWJAB